# What game? Matching dice with two each of d4, d6, d8, and d10

Tags: identify-this-game, dice

I bought this game at gen con in 2015. It is not dissimilar to Yahtzee or Farkle. I'd given it to my grandmother as a gift, but she has misplaced it.

You have two four-sided dice, two six-sided dice, two eight-sided dice, and two ten-sided dice.

During your turn, you get 3 rolls. You can set aside dice to match or (re)roll them, with your goal being to get matching pairs or better.

For example, I think that two 8s would be eight points, but three 8s would be sixteen points.

I can't remember the name or the other rules.

Comment: Do you still own the game?

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 no, I do not.... well, I have the requisite polyhedron, because I play D&D, but not the specific game that was purchased, no. I will make some updates so that this is more clear.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ah-ha. I searched for the 2015 gen con convention map, looked up the booth number and found the associated store.

### *Lumps*, by Continuum Games

There are a couple of printings, with various packaging and dice colorings (I'm a bit partial to the coal-colored ones).

https://continuumgames.com/shop/lumps-non-seasonal-edition/

As mentioned in the question, a matched pair gives the face-value of those dice, with additional matching dice increasing the total by the face-value again (two 2s are two points, three 2s are four points, etc). First player to 100 points wins.

Later printings include additional rules, such as a solitaire mode, which is just a race to 100 points; a hard mode where you have to set aside dice every roll  instead of banking on the last roll to save you, and some other quirky optional rules, such as all even numbers granting a bonus (or odd numbers).